# Jasper Reports Alternative for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jasper-reports

What are the alternative for Jasper Reports that works in Google App Engine? Anyone tried?

Thanks.

Comment: We did not find any. Whitelisted classes are limited so it is hard to produce reports graphic.

Comment: Are you trying to use Jasper reports on top the GAE datastore or in conjunction with Google Cloud SQL? (I suspect the former will require re-write of the querying engine.)

Comment: have you ever tried this one? https://code.google.com/p/g2-report-engine/

Answer (score 0):

We tried a variant with [JasperReports® Server](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server) on Compute Engine or Kubernetes but there are problems with the authentication;

[AppEngine URLFetchService removing custom response header attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163680/appengine-urlfetchservice-removing-custom-response-header-attribute/45164536#45164536)

The "Set-Cookie" attribute never appears in the response header even though the JasperReports server returns a 200 OK status for the login POST request.

Otherwise this would be a nice reporting solution for the Google Cloud platform.