# JasperReports® Server login not working from Google App Engine (due to missing header attribute)

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, jasper-reports, restlet, jasperserver

I'm trying to make a REST call (using the Restlet framework) from Google App Engine to a JasperReports server that I have running on Google Compute Engine. To use the JasperReports REST interface you need to first login by sending a POST request (with no body) and username/password query params.

http:///jasperserver/rest/login?j_username=&j_password=

The JasperReports server will respond by adding a "Set-Cookie" request header attribute. The attribute value contains a session ID that you use for any subsequent requests, thereby preserving session state across multiple requests. An example of this attribute is

Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=488AAF4E493E1FE5BEA25F6D71C025F3; Path=/jasperserver; HttpOnly

When I use a stand-alone Apache HTTP client, everything works fine. The JR server returns the Set-Cookie attribute and I insert it back into the header of any subsequent requests (report executions, report status, details, etc.).

However, when I try to do the same using the Restlet framework on Google App Engine (which uses the URLFetchService under the hood) the "Set-Cookie" attribute never appears in the response header even though the JasperReports server returns a 200 OK status for the login POST request.

Does anyone have experience with URLFetchService removing (custom) response header attributes?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check if header is case sensitive, try all lowercase?

Comment: Hi Alexander, the attribute is simply not there. If it was in lower-case I would have noticed but I'll check it to be absolutely sure, thanks.

Comment: Is far as i remember case is not important on client side. What I meant is try to return the header from your own code in different cases and see if all of them are working. Maybe some get dropped?

Answer (score 0):

Removing (custom) response header attributes would be an Google App Engine bug because the documentation states;

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/outbound-requests